# Good way for a CancellationToken to affect a subset of tasks controlled by another CancellationToken

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

Is there a ways to tie a cancellation token to a subset of tasks controlled by another cancellation token?... in this example I create two cancellationTokenSource's... and register one against the Cancel function of the other... this way if I cancel the loading of images... it only cancels those tasks... but if I cancel all... it cancels all tasks... Is there a better way to do this? (this ways seems messy... e.g. when to unregister)

```
CancellationTokenSource CancelAllSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadUrl(i, CancelAllSource.Token); });

CancellationTokenSource CancelImageLoadsSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

// this would connect the cancel all token to the cancel image loads token
CancelAllSource.Token.Register(CancelImageLoadsSource.Cancel, false);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { LoadImage(i, CancelImageLoadsSource.Token); });

...

CancelImageLoadsSource.Cancel(); // would cancel only the LoadImage tasks
// or
CancelAllSource.Cancel(); // would cancel all tasks (including the LoadImage tasks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is.

You can use `CreateLinkedTokenSource`* which created a `CancellationTokenSource` you can cancel yourself, but would also automatically be canceled when the token is signaled:

```
var cancelAllSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancelImageLoadsSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancelAllSource.Token);
```

> Creates a CancellationTokenSource that will be in the canceled state when any of the source tokens in the specified array are in the canceled state.

From [CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642252(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

<sup>* If you look at the [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs) it isn't the same, but it's pretty close to using `CancellationToken.Register` as you are doing</sup>